# FirefoxDriver: how does the browser gets open automatically

Tags: java, selenium

Inside main method if I write `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` and execute the class how does the browser gets open automatically

```
public class Web{

    public Static void main(String[] args){

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    }

}
```

Comment: It's not "automatically", it's `new FirefoxDriver();`

Comment: Thanks Elliott, my question is if we create new FirefoxDriver(), internally what code will get executed.

Comment: If only there was [somewhere](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/2.47.1/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.java#FirefoxDriver.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) you could look.

Answer (score 0):

> Firefox driver is included in the selenium-server-stanalone.jar available in the downloads. The driver comes in the form of an xpi (firefox extension) which is added to the firefox profile when you start a new instance of FirefoxDriver.

You can read up more on the Firefox Driver [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver).

If I misunderstood the question and you want to know how to open a browser and go to a URL, the below example will open the Firefox browser and go to http://www.google.com/

```
public class Web{
     public Static void main(String[] args){
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("http://www.google.com");
     }
}
```

Selenium has quite extensive documentation on WebDriver available [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp). I suggest you read the documentation to get to know Selenium better!

Comment: Thanks Quwin,But my question is if we create a new FirefoxDriver(), will any code in FirefoxDriver class will get executed like constructor code

Comment: Ah, sorry. In short; yes, it executes code in `FirefoxDriver` class. `new FirefoxDriver()` is calling the constructor of `FirefoxDriver`. Any more than that, I don't know. The others suggested to read the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/2.47.1/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.java#FirefoxDriver.%3Cinit%3E%28%29), and that would be my best bet too. Good luck!